# I can't use an ofstream object inside of a class in a header file in C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm making a header file in C++ to log stuff into a file, but an error occurs when I try to do so.

I've tried ofstream, fstream, and I've also tried opening the file separate from the object declaration. I tried getting rid of the variable and just putting the actual filename I wanted in there (so instead of logging(fileName) I put logging("fileName.txt"))

```
    void writeLog(){
        using namespace std;
        ofstream logging(fileName);
        if(!logging){
            cerr << "Error opening log file " << fileName << ". Logs are not being recorded\n";
            isError = true;
        }
```

I expect the code to create an object of ofstream called logging with the name of logging, which creates a file with a filename which is specified, but instead I get the error :

> no matching function for call to > 'std::basic_fstream::basic_fstream(std::__cxx11::string&)'|

Comment: It looks like your compiler is old and requires the file name to be a const char* instead of a std::string. In that case you need to replace `fileName` with `fileName.c_str()`

Comment: @drescherjm by curiosity why you say that in a remark rather than an answer ? (I mean an answer is more visible and allows to mark the question solved)

Answer (score 1):

As said in a remark by @drescherjm : your compiler is old and requires the file name to be a `char*` instead of a `std::string`. In that case you need to replace `fileName` with `fileName.c_str()`

Comment: Oh, thanks. So if I update my compiler should it work?

Comment: Yes since the 2011 standard this should work (c++11). You may just need to enable c++11.

Comment: @drescherjm I never understood why the first versions wasn't compatible with a std:string